# Microsoft Access, Splitting Error

Tags: ms-access

I'm implementing my first Access Database. I've read numerous guides/manuals, and I believe I'm nearly at the finish line. The Access Database will be used by 3-4 users.

I have three tables, all of which are "live" connections to three different Excel file. These Excel files are on a shared drive, which are to be updated periodically by the different users.

I have a single query that uses each of the different tables (3).

The goal is to give the users the ability to view the output of the query. From my understanding, the best way to structure Access is to split the database. I'd like the three tables to be stored in the "Back-End" database, and the Query to be on the "Front-End" database.

The issue that I'm running into is that, when using the "Database Splitter", I'm given the error "There are no tables in this database. The back-end database will be empty". I've searched for the past couple hours, but I can't seem to find a reason for this error. I believe it is quite clear that I do indeed have tables. What am I missing? Any input/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Database Splitter" can be used when you have tables and front-end things in your database. The "Splitter" would then create an additional Access database, "move" the tables to the new database and create linked tables in the old database that map the the tables in the new database. You already have linked tables, so there's nothing to split (your linked tables are not even Access tables).

Comment: Thank you Kais. Just for clarification. When you say "front-end things", do you mean Forms & Reports? And what would my Query be considered, back-end?

Comment: I consider all things  other than the data (tables) as "front-end" things. Queries too belong to the front-end, especially in MS Access, because they are useless in a back-end database (you can link tables but you can't link queries).

Comment: If my Excel files contain all the data, wouldn't those connection tables be considered my back-end? Thanks again, I'm just trying to really grasp the concept.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to explain. The Excel files are your back-end and trey are already split from your front-end (by nature). The Access database is the front-end and it reaches out for the data using "linked tables" (which are no real tables but only links).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up Kais, you've been very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @MarioS Glad to hear that, Mario. Just call me *Wolfgang*. :-)