# Microsoft Access, other users cannot open tables/query

Tags: ms-access

I finished up an Access database recently. I'm working on splitting the database so that the users only have access to the "Front-End".

However, I'm running into an issue that I don't quite understand. The database has three tables, all of which are live connections to Excel Files. These Excel Files are all located on a common drive that all of the users have access to (including myself). We all have the drive mapped to the same letter (X).

However, when they open the Access file and attempt to open a table or query, they are prompted with a "Not a Valid Path" error. Why are they prompted by this error? The Access database is looking at three files within the X-Drive, which all of the users have the ability to open. When I open the file, I do not run into this issue. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does every user have his own copy of the front-end database? Did you create these copies before linking the tables on the network drive? Where do the links point to in the user's front-end databases?

Comment: Sounds like should work. Set table links with UNC (Universal Naming Convention) that uses server name instead of drive letter path and drive mapping is not an issue. Use VBA code to set the link to UNC path. Then distribute user copies.

Comment: Do you have Frontend linked to Backend, Backend linked to Excel? That's not going to work, see your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642651/microsoft-access-splitting-error).

Comment: I have not split the database between front-end & back-end. It is currently just an Access File that makes a connection to three Excel files. All of the files (including the Access database) are located on the same drive, all of which the users have access to. June7, I'll try the UNC connection, thank you!

Comment: Fixed!! I used the Linked Table Manager and inserted the document location instead of browsing for it. The users are now able to access the tables/query. Thank you June7 for pointing me in the right direction.